# Is there a python equivalent of Ruby's 'rvm'?

Tags: python, egg, equivalent, rvm

**Q:** Do we have anything functionally equivalent in Python to the [Ruby version manager 'rvm'](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/)?

---

(*RVM* lets you easily switch **completely** between different versions of the ruby interpreter **and** different sets of gems (modules). Everything concerning download-build-install-switch  of interpreter(-s) and gems gets taken care of by invoking rvm. It is all run under your regular user account.)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

<strike>Yes, it is [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) along with [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/).</strike>

update: you may install both at once with [virtualenv burrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito).

**Update**: the correct answer is now probably [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

For scientific computing, the corresponding tool is [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: Ah, yeah because virtualenv by itself is too low level for pretty much any use other than creating your own wrapper... Thanks for the pointer, I'm looking at http://vimeo.com/5894881 now :)

Comment: I'm confused.  Where can you install different versions of python?  It seems to be just using the system's version of python.

Comment: Each virtualenv is tied to a particular version of Python. You may thus use different versions of Python across your virtualenvs.

Comment: But is there a way to bundle a specific Python install (say, 2.7) with certain eggs in one project, and with certain other eggs in another?  RVM manages all this stuff seamlessly, and `sudo` is a thing of the past.

Comment: Virtualenv allows to juggle between versions of Python, and between different sets of eggs; but it won't deal with the compilation+installation of Python itself. RVM does exactly that for Ruby. If you want to build a specific version of Python because you can't install it out of packages for some reason, then you want to check pythonbrew instead (just the other answer just below).

Comment: I don't see how this supports several versions of python.

Comment: RVM does take care for compiling Ruby interpreters. It also allows downloading precompiled ones, if available.

Comment: I really like your use of strikethrough to show what used to work compared to what you felt was best after your latest edit.

Comment: @docwhat this is now possible it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268119/895245

Answer (score 86):

### Pythonbrew is no longer under development. The former maintainer suggests to use "PyEnv" instead (see below)".

pythonbrew has come!
http://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew

pyenv: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Comment: Interesting, might be worth a try. I see that its command invocations are quite similar that of to `rvm`...

Comment: As someone who is quite adept to rvm, pythonbrew was an absolute breeze to get accustomed to. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe this is the real answer from now on.

Comment: Should add be good to see pypy and jython added to the list of known pythons.

Comment: Not that much of traffic anymore. Is this still worth looking into?

Comment: but it only supports CPython, not Jython and pypy. RVM supports all kinds of Rubies.

Comment: Now the readme file says that it "is no longer under active development". :(

Answer (score 52):

I created [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) which is a fork of Ruby's [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and modified for Python. Like pythonz, pyenv also supports Stackless, PyPy, and Jython.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on hytdsh's answer (nearly two years later)...

[pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) a fork of pythonbrew that adds support for Stackless, PyPy, and Jython.

If you like how rvm handles different interpreters, it may worth taking a look at pythonz. If you're strictly working with CPython, the difference is less significant.

Answer (score 5):

Optionally, if you're using Macports you can use `python_select`.
Install `python_select` with:

```
$ sudo port install python_select
```

Assuming python 2.6 and 2.5 have bee installed via Macports you can switch pythons like so:

```
$ sudo python_select python25
=> Selecting version "python25" for python
$ python --version
=> 2.5.5
$ sudo python_select python26
=> Selecting version "python26" for python
$ python --version
=> 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 2):

**pyenv 1.2.15 can build and install Python for you**

Maybe this was not possible in earlier version, but when I tested in 1.2.15 I noticed the `pyenv install` option which worked:

```
pyenv install 3.8.0
```

Therefore I feel that it is reasonable to call `pyenv` a replacement for RVM.

I have given a fully detailed example of its usage at: [apt-get install for different python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions/59268046#59268046)