# How to install pip for Python 2

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, apt-get

I run

```
python --version
```

and get

```
Python 2.7.3
```

I run

```
pip --version
```

and get

```
pip 1.5 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-1.5-py3.2.egg (python 3.2)
```

I installed `pip` using `apt-get`. How to I get the Python 2 version of `pip`?

I've reinstalled `python` and `python-pip` several times with `apt-get`. I'm also curious why these would install different Python versions.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960805/apt-get-install-for-different-python-versions) question is similar or duplicate for this when you try to install using apt-get

Answer (score 85):

To install pip for Python2 on Ubuntu, this worked for me

```
sudo apt update
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

It's based on DareDevil7's answer but notice the url is different.

Comment: you don't need to sudo; installing in user-space is fine

Comment: This works even though pip officially dropped support for Python2.

Comment: Amazing that people are still installing Python2 in 2024...

Answer (score 6):

If there are both python2.7 and python3 in you ubuntu system,run this

`sudo apt install python-pip`

There will be `pip` for python3 ,`pip2` for python2

Comment: `Unable to locate package python-pip`

Comment: This answer is incorrect now that python2.7 is out of support.

Comment: Not found check your command again.

Comment: This works beautifully for ubuntu:trusty, whereas python2 get-pip.py doesn't work (results in "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)" )

Answer (score 6):

run this

```
python2.7 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Comment: Very useful.  Needed pip to install virtualenv for supporting legacy code on AWS Linux.  Also appreciated (a) no need for internet access (b) support of --user option to keep things isolated.  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the only way to install `pip2` using the `python2.7` package from the distribution repository on modern Fedora Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you use [`pyenv`](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to manage multiple versions of Python, because it can often get problematic. Right now the solution to the problem would depend on the configuration you have for pip and python in your bash.

One thing you *can* do is download the [`easy_install`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html) script, and use python 3 to run it and install pip for python 3 alone.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to install pip globally for your system use the get-pip.py script with the wanted python binary http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip

```
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

But you should consider using virtualenv / buildout to get an isolated environment

Comment: `File "/tmp/tmpNoRNRb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60` `sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: That syntax (`f"ERROR: {exc}"`) is only in Python 3

Comment: So that version of `get-pip.py` is for Python 3 and this answer is wrong, see Edward Gaere's answer

Answer (score 2):

Download the `tar.gz` of pip from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads.

Unzip or Untar, Then from its untar directory install for any specific version of python using

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

or

```
python3.3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following Commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead

Answer (score 0):

Its a not a good idea to install pip for python2 system wide. I guess, you need to run a project with python2. The best solution is `vritualenv`.
I am making an assumption that in your installation `which python2` returns `/usr/bin/python2.7` and `virtualenv --version` returns `virtualenv 20.15.1 from home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.pyc`

```
   1  virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 YOURPROJECT
   2. source YOURPROJECT/bin/activate
```

The last command will now activate the virtual environment and in this environment, your python is python2.7 and pip is installed for python2.7 as well.
You can deactivate your virtual environment using `deactivate`.