# Installing biopython for python2

Tags: linux, python-2.7, biopython

I have python 2 and 3 installed and need to run a script written for python 2. Said script needs biopython. So, how do I install biopython such that it's available specifically for python 2? (Linux environment btw). Thanks!

Comment: `pip install biopython`  --  https://github.com/biopython/biopython ...or... `python -m pip install biopython`

Comment: Consider using conda and installing in separate environment.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I actually tried pip already but I can only use for python 3. If you can help me install pip for python 2 I think I should good!

Comment: Regarding the conda/separate environment option, how would I do this? Can you post a link? Thanks!

Comment: python -m pip install biopython returns 'Requirement already satisfied: biopython in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.78)'. I need it to be installed in python2.6.6

Comment: python2.7 -m pip <commands>

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I found my way through it and am sharing.

Install pip for Python2.7 as given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719099/4616962

Then download biopython 1.76 http://biopython.org/DIST/biopython-1.76.tar.gz as it is the last release to support python2.7

Follow the README.rst for the installation