# Unable to install http module

Tags: python, pip

My Ubuntu server version is 22.04 and Python is 3.10.6.
And the pip version is 22.0.2

```
pip install htttp
```

The above command was entered to install the http module, but an error occurred.

```
Collecting http
Downloading http-0.02.tar.gz (32 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [31 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wt_twpw1/http_e204a51ec15142428e42fe97cce6fbe8/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      import http
    File "/tmp/pip-install-wt_twpw1/http_e204a51ec15142428e42fe97cce6fbe8/http/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
      from request import Request
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
  Error in sys.excepthook:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
      from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
      from apport.report import Report
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
      from urllib.request import urlopen
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
      import http.client
    File "/tmp/pip-install-wt_twpw1/http_e204a51ec15142428e42fe97cce6fbe8/http/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
      from request import Request
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

Looking at the error contents, it seemed that the request module was not installed.
so

```
pip install request
```

However, the request module also cannot be installed.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for request
```

I need some help.

Answer (score 3):

Python3 contains http package by default.
**You don't need to install it.**

Just do `import http` at your script, it will run fine.

Comment: I didn't see under the lamp.
thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

I found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305524/how-to-install-pip-for-python-2). Install pip2 and python2. Then, type:

> pip2 install http

So I think, this is the only way.