# Pyenv choose virtualenv directory

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I just began to use pyenv to manage my python versions, and began to use the pyenv virtualenv plugin to manage my virtualenvs, and so far, I have loved it. One thing I miss however, is that with virtualenv, you could actually place virtual environments in repository directories so that your repository was a completely reproducible environment. Does anyone know of a way to choose the directory of your virtualenv in pyenv?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer:  You can’t, as far as I know.

It wouldn’t really work either, right?  If you use `pyenv virtualenv` to install a virtualenv into a repo, and you clone that repo to another machine… how would `pyenv` on the new machine know to take control of the virtualenv in the repository?

Also, “you probably shouldn’t do that”.  Virtualenvs are not 100% decoupled from the underlying Python installation, and aren’t really all that portable.  And do you really want to litter your repositories with a bunch of easily replicated junk?  The “right” way to go about things is probably to to maintain a `requirements.txt` for pip — that way you can easily reproduce your development environment wherever you clone your repo.

*That all said*, there’s nothing stopping you from using plain old `virtualenv` to create a virtualenv anywhere you like, even if you installed `virtualenv` into a Python interpreter under `pyenv` control.  That virtualenv itself will of course *not* be administered by `pyenv`, but you can still use it as you always did…

Comment: As someone looking at this question, I have a `requirements.txt` and a script that generates a virtualenv. I want a command that looks in the current path for virtualenvs, and don't want to manage "global" virtualenvs. I want my virtualenv to exist in a directory.

Comment: you can and it is easy and not bothersome at all - I have added my usual workflow [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019181/4034083).

Answer (score 9):

I use the following commands:

```
pyenv local 3.9.16
```

And then

```
python -m venv virtualenv
```

It works

Answer (score 6):

Here is a GitHub issue on the project tracker asking about this: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/802

The [reply by a project collaborator was](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/802#issuecomment-273120383):

> You can just create virtualenv in any location. To use it from pyenv, create symlink to the environment in ~/.pyenv/versions

although I must say I'm [not very satisfied with this solution](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/802#issuecomment-564023817).

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround

In your project directory, create a `.python-version` file. Assuming you already installed some virtual environment using `pyenv-virtualenv`, then append this line to it(you may want to change the version number):

```
3.7.1/envs/your-project-name@3.7.1
```

Whenever you enter into the directory, the correct python version will be used, and it works pretty well.

Comment: Alternatively pyenv will create this file for you in your current path with the command `pyenv local <name_of_virtualenv>`.

Comment: Could there be a global location of this file

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
pyenv install -s 3.8.3 # install preferred version if needed
PYENV_VERSION=3.8.3 python -m venv /tmp/your/prefered/dir ; source /tmp/your/prefered/dir/activate
```

Note that this method uses venv, not virtualenv, which is slightly different, but a part of a standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I use the simple recipe of

1. `python -m venv virt` to create the local venv
2. Link the venv to pyenv with `ln -s <local virt> ~/.pyenv/versions/<venv name>`
3. Now you can do `pyenv local <venv name>` and all other normal operations from pyenv with this venv.

---

For the interested I have made two CLIs

- [`pyenv-here`](https://github.com/jakob1379/.dotfiles/blob/master/bin/bin/pyenv-here) to create a new venv and set local dir in one go
- [`pyenv-link`](https://github.com/jakob1379/.dotfiles/blob/master/bin/bin/pyenv-link) to link a local virt to pyenv

Comment: This should be the acccepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Slightly left-field answer, but I ended up writing a hacky equivalent of pyenv that looks for a virtualenv in a directory and its parents because pyenv doesn't really seem to support this as [layed out in the answer about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59267972/1892584).

I called this script `enpy`, put it on my path and then called e.g.  `enpy -c import sys; print(sys.executable)`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys

from pathlib import Path


NAMES = ("venv", "env", ".env", ".venv")


def find_python():
    cwd = Path(os.getcwd())
    for direc in [cwd] + list(cwd.parents):
        for p in NAMES:
            venv = direc / p
            if venv.exists():
                return venv / "bin" / "python"
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not find python")


python = find_python()
os.execvp(str(python), [str(python)] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The top comment is wrong; you certainly can.

Once you create your virtual environment with `pyenv virtualenv 3.9.15 your-environment-name`, you can specify the directories in which this environment will be used automatically with the following command. In your desired directory, run:

```
pyenv local your-environment-name
```

The command will create the necessary `.python-version` file that includes the name of your environment. From now on, every time you enter the folder, the specified environment will be used.

Comment: The question refers to where the `venv`dir is gonna be located, not what's gonna activate when you enter,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use pyenv specific python version and create virtual env from it in wanted directory, you can for example do this:

`~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/bin/python -m venv my/path/to/venv`

Answer (score -1):

To build on-top of a previous comment, you can add this to your .zshrc:

```
pyC () {
    location="requirements.txt"
    venvName=".venv"
    
    # Parse flags
    while getopts "r:e:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            e) venvName=$OPTARG ;;
            r) location=$OPTARG ;;
            \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" ;;
            :) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument.";;
        esac
    done

    # Remove existing virtual environment if it exists
    [ -d $venvName ] && rm -rf $venvName
    
    # Determine Python version (global or local)
    pyVersion=$( [ -f .python-version ] && echo "local" || echo "global" )

    # Check pyVersion, create version file, virtual environment, activate it
    pyenv version-name $pyVersion | xargs -I {} pyenv local {} && python -m venv $venvName
    source $venvName/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip
    
    # Install requirements if file exists, otherwise print message
    [ -f $location ] && pip install -r $location || echo -e "\nFile $location not found"
}
```