# How can I install multiple versions of Python on latest OS X and use them in parallel?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I want to run tests with multiple Python versions on OS X 10.11, including:

- Python 2.6 - ?!
- Python 2.7 - default - solved
- Python 3.4 - ?!
- Python 3.5 - installed via brew - works well
- Conda Python 3.5 - ?!

I want to run the tests via `tox` so tox needs to be able to find them. Sadly it seems that brew doesn't want to install 3.4 since they added 3.5 and I obviously do not want to remove 3.5 one.

Comment: This may help: [Is there a python equivalent of Ruby's 'rvm'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812471/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rubys-rvm)

Answer (score 85):

`pyenv` is the thing you want. It works very very well:

> pyenv lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python. It's simple, unobtrusive, and follows the UNIX tradition of single-purpose tools that do one thing well. This project was forked from rbenv and ruby-build, and modified for Python.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Install it via Homebrew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv
```

It handles the **download, compilation, and installation** of various pythons for you, e.g.:

```
$ pyenv install 3.7.2
```

It can show you which versions you've installed, and which is active:

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.6.7
* 3.7.2
```

When you're in a new project directory, just tell pyenv which python version to use there:

```
$ pyenv local 3.6.7  # Because e.g. tensorflow isn't compat. with 3.7 :-(
```

You can set a 'default' version everywhere else:

```
$ pyenv global 3.7.2
```

Comment: Also requires 
brew postinstall python3
so that pip3 is available.

Comment: in current version pip3 is directly available after you run pyenv install 3.x.y

Comment: pyenv or asdf cannot install m1/arm64 Python on macOS 12.x

Comment: pyenv is great. I have noticed one flaw - in comparison of with the 'brew solution - you can't update the version of pip coming with it. Is it correct?

Comment: Pyenv is great. Dont forget to add ~/.pyenv/shims to the PATH variable to pick up the pyenv version of python, so that the global set version can be picked up by default

Comment: Don't forget also running `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` after the Brew installation. [Details here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv)

Answer (score 56):

`brew` alone has been sufficient for me to use multiple versions of Python. I haven't needed `pyenv` or `conda` for it.

To install various versions using `brew`, run commands such as:

```
brew install python@3.9
brew install python@3.8
```

When creating a virtual environment, create it using one of:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin
```

Please list the `bin` directory above using `ls` in order to find and use the python executable in it.

For macOS M1 (not Intel) (see also, [M1 brew setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67271753/1736679)), modify brew install path, eg:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/bin
```

Please list the `bin` directory above using `ls` in order to find and use the python executable in it.

Lastly, the version of `/usr/local/bin/python3` is probably not the version you want for your virtual environment.

Comment: @kd12345 You do not have to unlink or link to "navigate between versions". Instead use virtual environments for your projects.

Comment: In Big Sur (with zsh) this doesn't work for me; I get permission denied when trying to call `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin`.

Comment: You don't need to avoid using python3 when creating a virtual env, since the python version inside that env will always be the same

Comment: @Asclepius I understand you're point, just saying that, as long as you know which version of python3 you're using when you create your virtual env, within that venv if you call `python3` (not with its full path), that would be the version that created that virtual env, no matter if python3 was upgraded outside that venv.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Instead of forcing any particular version, the above solution can be used to create multiple virtual environments with different python versions.

Comment: @Drenai Please find and use the python executable in the `bin` directory you noted (using `ls`).

Comment: To create a venv using a Python version installed in this manner, do something like: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.13_1/bin/python3.8 -m venv SomeVenv` (M1, MacOS 12.4)

Comment: Here is how you can find the path `$(brew --prefix python@3.9)/bin`

Answer (score 24):

This [blog post](http://blog.pinaxproject.com/2015/12/08/how-test-against-multiple-python-versions-parallel/) suggests using `pyenv` with the desired `detox`. The basic setup with `brew` requires:

```
brew install pyenv pyenv-virtualenv pyenv-virtualenvwrapper
```

Then installing the desired Python versions with `pyenv install [version]`, **rather than** installing Python using `brew`. You can check the available versions using `pyenv versions`.

Finally, `pip install detox` will ensure you've got `tox` and `detox` installed. Then you should be able to specify the desired testing versions in your `tox.ini`.

Comment: Note that detox is [allegedly unmaintained](https://pypi.org/project/detox/) at this point.

Comment: Unmaintained, and now incompatible with newer versions of tox.

Answer (score 10):

As previous answers also mentioned.. no pyenv needed, this works perfect for me:

```
brew install python@3.7
brew install python@3.8
brew install python@3.9
```

Then just add the corresponding version lines to the  ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin"
```

Comment: Would you only add one of those paths in bash at a time?

Comment: no, all at the same time.  it's possible because each path has inside a bin file with different name.. e.g python3.8

Comment: +1 I just discovered `brew --prefix` .. so put his in my rc: `for pyver in 3.7 3.8 3.10 3.9; do export PATH=$PATH:$(brew --prefix python@$pyver)/bin; done`

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend using a package manager such as `Anaconda`, https://www.continuum.io/downloads, which it makes it trivially easy to install different self-contained `virtual-envs`.

For example, to create a virtual environment with `numpy` and `Python 2.7` this is the command:

`conda create --name py2_env numpy python=2.7`

And then to switch to that environment:

`source activate py2_env`

Comment: This is not an option because it works only with conda and I am looking for something that works with more than conda.

Answer (score 0):

`pyenv` is all well and good but I feel that we should give a mention to the wonderful `pipenv` library from Kenneth Reitz.

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

It provides the functionality of pyenv plus dependency locking, support for `.env` out-of-the-box and much more.

Comment: Pipenv can only use the versions of python that are already installed, so that does not help with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend DO NOT USE pyenv in most cases. You will face deep problems with pyenv - check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66797993/10849913

Comment: When you say "don't do this", it's also necessary to suggest an alternative. Currently, this answer does not really address the question.

Comment: Brew works for me - described already in answers above.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding below may help manage different versions of python:

```
      python3.10 -> python3.10 has its own pip module 
                -> how to install?
                  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
                  sudo  /opt/local/bin/python3.10  get-pip.py
                      -> package is installed based on this pip, it belong to python3.10
                        /opt/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip install pandas
                              -> package location
                              /Users/frank/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages

      python3.9 -> python3.9 has its own pip module 
                -> how to install?                  
                  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
                  sudo  /opt/local/bin/python3.9  get-pip.py
                      -> package is installed based on this pip, it belong to python3.9
                          /opt/local/bin/python3.9 -m pip install pandas
                              -> package location
                                /Users/frank/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
```