# How to downgrade python from 3.9.0 to 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I'm trying to install PyAudio but it needs a Python 3.6 installation and I only have Python 3.9 installed. I tried to switch using brew and pyenv but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you Windows, Mac or Linux user?

Comment: They mentioned "brew" so probably Mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install multiple versions of Python on latest OS X and use them in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968425/how-can-i-install-multiple-versions-of-python-on-latest-os-x-and-use-them-in-par)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install multiple versions of the same major python 3.x version, as long as the minor version is different in this case x here refers to the minor version, and you could delete the no longer needed version at anytime since they are kept separate from each other.

so go ahead and install python 3.6 since it's a different minor from 3.9, and you could then delete 3.9 if you would like to since it would be used over 3.6 by the system, unless you are going to specify the version you wanna run.