# What is the best way to uninstall python 3.9 and install python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm looking to work with Tensorflow and just noticed that TensorFlow isn't yet compatible with Python 3.9 which is what I have installed on my machine.

I was wondering if you have a quick and easy way for me to move over to Python 3.8.

Comment: Which package/software manager are you using? What is the location of the current Python installation. How did you install python3.8 in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install multiple versions of Python on latest OS X and use them in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968425/how-can-i-install-multiple-versions-of-python-on-latest-os-x-and-use-them-in-par)

Comment: A quick question about the above solution, should I uninstall any existing version of python first?

Comment: If you are using conda environment, just create a new environment and specify python version to 3.8

Comment: Please answer @Oussama 's question first.

Comment: This is terrible with newer versions of Python that are not compatible with the machine learning module package. So my approach is to keep the existing version 3.9 and the computer is using Anaconda to install a virtual environment with 3.7. When using vscode or pycharm, just remember to set it to that 3.7 Python environment.